# Manually added SDK cannot use project other frameworks (like SwiftyJson)

Tags: ios, xcode

I added a Sdk manually in Xcode.
the steps are these:

> 1. Build phases -> Copy bundle resource     
>    I added the sdk to the project
> 2. Build phases -> Linked Binary with Library    
>     added the framework to the project
>
>    It still had error that Could not import the sdk.
> 3. General -> embeded Binaries 
>      added the framework here

I have some dependencies like SwiftyJson in my project which I added them using pod file.
This framework also uses SwiftyJson. but it has this error:

> No such module 'Starscream'

Comment: Make sure you open .workspace not .xcodeproj as many time error related to this.

Comment: @CodeChanger Thanks. Yes I opened .workspace

Comment: You added .xcodeproj file of this framework in your project and build it right ?

Comment: And why you choose manual as you said that you are already using PODs in your app so any specific reason to add this lib manually ?

Comment: @CodeChanger Yes, exactly. because the didn't have their Sdk on Cocoapods and I have to use it

Comment: They have their SDK on cocoapods

Comment: You are looking for `Starscream` library for WebSocket right ?

Comment: @CodeChanger No, That Sdk want to use it

Comment: Can  you share link of library so I can check and guide you more on this ?

Comment: @CodeChanger , Did you solved this issue ?